# React Native Expo CLI not hitting VSCode Debug Breakpoints using Attach to Packager

Tags: react-native, expo, vscode-debugger

I place a breakpoint on a simple console.log line of code, and debug with Attach to packager. The statement prints just fine, but it acts as if that breakpoint isn't even there.

I am following the React Native Tutorial for Beginners video by Programming With Mosh on Youtube. I have set up my react native and my debugger. This is my launch.json file:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to packager",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "type": "reactnative",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 19000, //correct port. have tried with and without quotes and also no port variable
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

1. First I place a breakpoint on a simple console.log statement. The breakpoint is fully red.
2. Then I run "npm start" to start.
3. Then I debug with Attach to packager. The debug console prints "Established a connection with the Proxy (Packager) to the React Native application" and the little debug window with the code step controls appears.
4. I type "a" to open Android
5. I reload the app. The statement prints, but the code never stops at the breakpoint and allows me to step through the next lines.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

when your app is in run mode then open your Terminal then **hit M** then press Debug in your emulator or device.
Then the browser opens then **press F12** which will open DeveloperTools.
Then reload your app with the help of the terminal then you are able to see logs and breakpoints on browser developer tools.

if you are still not able to debug so Follow this [link](https://docs.expo.dev/debugging/tools/) for debugging.